# How to fit sticky footer to its container inner background color

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar

Adding Styesheet as

```
.container
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

I will get this

[image]

But I need this

[image]

What should I do as footer background stick in bottom but in container background color?

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: as see the link and add stylesheet as container{background:yellow;} i need it fully not half

Comment: Add `height: calc( 100vh - 60px);` to the `.container` but I don't know the structure of your html.

Comment: you can click the link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar and add style as container{background:yellow;} and see the effect as i need fully yellow background not half

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; spacing.

Comment: @Anubhav actually nice color choice for a web site.

Comment: its not the color for site actully i am seeing the issue through the color ok

Answer (score 0):

you can set the containers height to 100% or to 100vh (viewport height) setting its box-sizing property to border-box

Comment: as container height 100% and box-sizing not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your problem

```
.container
{
    min-height: 100vh; // window_height
}
```